How do I interpret these coordinates I got from the website of the german statistical bureau?
Thanks for clicking.
During my research, I stumbled upon the "Unfallatlas", which is essentially a collection of all the accidents that happened in a specific year. For me, only the coordinates are important. But I need to convert them into "standard" GPS coordinates or in other words, coordinates how google would use them.
But in the .csv, they are present in two different systems.
In UTM ETRS89, Zone 32N : 593821, 621226734016091
and in
Decimal degree WGS84: 6014331, 532445689663291
(Yes, both of these coordinates should correspond to the same place)
I already tried writing a python script and various online converters, but none resulted in valid coordinates.
If someone could help me, how to interpret these numbers and/or how to convert them, that would be really appreciated.

I think you are missing the decimal separator (or treating them as faulty thousands separators), which is a comma in these files, when reading in the CSV files.
The coordinates are likely
593821 [probably missing three decimals], 621226.734016091 in UTM ETRS89 Zone 32N
and
6.014331, 53.2445689663291 in WGS84
Is that any better?

Unfortunately, this is exactly how theses coordinates where published by the bureau.
If I try the WGS84, I get a point in the ocean.
From my understanding, every coordinate should be inside of germany

Are you opening the files in Excel or similar directly? excel would butcher the values immediately when opening a CSV file with the wrong language settings. I downloaded the 2022 CSV zip file from https://unfallatlas.statistikportal.de/ and the coordinates looked OK.

@d3vilstrap: you should probably invert the two coordinate in WGS84: usually we write latitude, longitude, but keep the x,y convention also with degrees (so inverted coordinates). In any case a statistical office should have also metadata documentations (and other documentation).

@GiacomoCatenazzi Yes, they have documentation, that's where I got the ETRS89 32N and WGS84 from. I just tried to convert those, but the numbers they gave didn't make sense to me.
Fortunately, I found out that the unlabeled (and not described in the metadata) columns contain the "normal" coordinates.

To this day, I couldn't find any solution on how to interpret the coordinates given in the stated forms.
The good thing is, I discovered that the unlabeled data at the end of the csv, are the "normal" coordinates, just divided in degrees/minutes etc.
